# Cannot run fetch gazebo simulator in Indigo

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has been almost 4~5 hours now for the error below:
I have installed ros-indigo (from source) on my ubuntu 16.04
Now I am trying to run fetch gazebo simulator by running: "roslaunch fetch_gazebo simulation.launch"
But, I cannot avoid the error msg below.
Can anyone help me ?

```
 ... logging to /home/hankm/.ros/log/8316172e-1167-11e8-9a7f-107b448e8cda/roslaunch-retina-22849.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 62, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 687, in main
    process_includes(doc, os.path.dirname(args[0]))
  File "/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 246, in process_includes
    filename_spec = eval_text(elt.getAttribute('filename'), {})
  File "/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 485, in eval_text
    results.append(handle_extension(lex.next()[1][2:-1]))
  File "/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 473, in handle_extension
    return eval_extension("$(%s)" % s)
  File "/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 66, in eval_extension
    return substitution_args.resolve_args(str, context=substitution_args_context, resolve_anon=False)
  File "/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 316, in resolve_args
    resolved = _resolve_args(resolved, context, resolve_anon, commands)
  File "/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 329, in _resolve_args
    resolved = commands[command](resolved, a, args, context)
  File "/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 157, in _find
    pkg_path = rp.get_path(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 203, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: fetch_description

ROS path [0]=/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share
ROS path [2]=/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/stacks

while processing /home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/fetch_gazebo/launch/include/fetch.launch.xml:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/xacro/xacro.py /home/hankm/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/fetch_gazebo/robots/fetch.gazebo.xacro] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find fetch_gazebo)/robots/fetch.gazebo.xacro" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282679/cannot-run-fetch-gazebo-simulator-in-indigo/) by [thezest](https://answers.ros.org/users/33702/thezest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Just out of curiosity: why did you install Indigo from source on 16.04?

**Comment by [thezest](https://answers.ros.org/users/33702/thezest/) on 2018-02-14**:
Indigo doesn't support ubuntu 16.04 if I am not mistaken...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
That is true. But the question was more: what made you install Indigo in the first place?

**Comment by [thezest](https://answers.ros.org/users/33702/thezest/) on 2018-02-14**:
Fetch recommends ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo
Unfortunately,  my linux box has 16.04. And I do not want to go back to 14.04

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Looks like work is underway to get things released on Kinetic: [fetchrobotics/fetch_gazebo#15](https://github.com/fetchrobotics/fetch_gazebo/issues/15). According to the last few commits it should already work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
As to your problem: do you have the `fetch_description` package in your workspace?

If you want to continue with your Indigo installation, I'd suggest creating an overlay workspace that extends your Indigo underlay. Then use regular `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`) again.

**Comment by [thezest](https://answers.ros.org/users/33702/thezest/) on 2018-02-14**:
According to their manual, I am supposed to install Indigo ( http://docs.fetchrobotics.com/gazebo.html#installation )
I didn't know fetch_gazebo is updated for ros-kinect.

Let me try your suggestion. Then, I will get back to you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
If at all possibe, I'd try to get the packages to work under Kinetic. Using a source install of Indigo under Xenial is a bit convoluted.

**Comment by [thezest](https://answers.ros.org/users/33702/thezest/) on 2018-02-14**:
You are right. But, the problem is the actual fetch robot in my lab is equipped with ros-indigo. :(

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
As long as the messages (and services, and actions) that you use between the two haven't changed, that should not be a problem.

**Comment by [thezest](https://answers.ros.org/users/33702/thezest/) on 2018-02-14**:
I don't think I can install fetch-gazebo-demo from sudo apt-get, do I?
How do you install fetch-gazebo-demo source into /opt/ros/kinect ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
No, not on Kinetic no. None of those pkgs have been released.

> How do you install fetch-gazebo-demo source into /opt/ros/kinect ?

I would not do that.

Just create a Catkin workspace, clone the pkgs and build them (using regular `catkin_make`).

Make sure to follow the issue I linked earlier.

**Comment by [thezest](https://answers.ros.org/users/33702/thezest/) on 2018-02-14**:
Man... What should I do with the source compiled indigo... Can I just remove the folder?
Any possibility of interfering pkg installed kinetic?
Thanks for your help anyway.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-15**:
So you've got the packages compiled and working in a Kinetic workspace?

> What should I do with the source compiled indigo... Can I just remove the folder?

if you don't have any use for it, then I would say, remove it.

**Comment by [thezest](https://answers.ros.org/users/33702/thezest/) on 2018-02-15**:
OK Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-15**:
So do you have things working?

**Comment by [thezest](https://answers.ros.org/users/33702/thezest/) on 2018-02-16**:
In my laptop I can launch Fetch Simulator. I can see all the topics.
But, I have another problem related to rviz now :(
Your advice helped me a lot though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Op had a source install of Indigo on Ubuntu Xenial that appeared to be missing (at least) the `fetch_description` package, which caused the problem.

Based on the work done in [fetchrobotics/fetch_gazebo#15](https://github.com/fetchrobotics/fetch_gazebo/issues/15), it appeared that installing the Fetch packages on Kinetic is now actually possible, so OP opted for that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1